# The product of four consecutive integers is one less than a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> Prove that the product of any four consecutive integers is one less than a perfect square.

My first idea is the let k be a member of the integers. Let $m$ which also belongs to the integers be equal to $k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)$. When I expanded, I ended up with $k^4 + 6k^3 + 11k^2 + 6k$. Now, my only suggestion is to compare with the form of a perfect square trinomial and show that it cannot be expressed in that form of $a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. Can someone help me to complete this?

Comment: Multiply the first and last and the second and third factors. $(k^2+3k)(k^2+3k+2)=[(k^2+3k)^2+2(k^2+3k)+1]-1=[(k^2+3k)+1]^2-1$.

Comment: How about adding $1$, and seeing if $k^4+6k^3+11k^2+6k+1$ is a square?

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$(x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)+1=(x^2-x-1)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that a number that's one less than a perfect square has two factors that are two apart: $y^2-1 = (y-1)(y+1)$.  If we can find a way to make the factors of $x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$ combine into two factors that are two apart, we win.

$$
\begin{align}
x(x+3)&=x^2+3x\\
(x+1)(x+2)&=x^2+3x+2
\end{align}
$$

That was easy.  So: $x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3) = y^2 - 1$ has the solution $y = x^2 + 3x + 1$.